# node.js: ng serve --open ― SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, intellij-idea, angular-cli

I am trying to run a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oRrXzIXE_E) `Angular` project in `Intellij` 2021 (on Ubuntu), and after creating the project, the next step is:

`ng serve --open` in the terminal.

Which gives the following error:

```
me@me:~/Projects/DemoApp$ ng serve --open
/home/me/Projects/DemoApp/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js:35
  );
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
me@me:~/Projects/DemoApp$
```

From looking at the code in `ng.js` it seems like it's a warning about node.js version (it's not clear to me what there is a Syntax Error).

What should I do to solve this problem?

I looked at the Intellij project settings, and in the `node.js` settings I see:

Node interpreter:
`~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea/node/node-v14.15.0-linux-x64/bin/node`

Package manager:
`~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea/node/node-v14.15.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm`

In the terminal I get:

```
$ nodejs --version
v4.2.6
```

and

```
$ npm --version
3.5.2
```

Comment: No, but is it not downloaded internally by Intellij when I create the project? There was a field to specify the location of Node.js, Intellij was not able to find it on my system so I used the default option which was "Download Node". I think this is why the node interpreter field shows Node-v14.15.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running `ng serve` in terminal, as far as I can see. In this case, your system Node.js interpreter (v. 4.2.6) is being used. But trailing commas in function calls are only supported since Node.js 8, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas#browser_compatibility. Thus the error. You need to update your system Node.js interpreter to LTS version

Comment: Yes! It worked! 4.2.6 was the node.js default version for my Ubuntu version. So I had to update node.js without apt-get. I did it with `npm` as is explained here https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version